# Сохранение информации из GridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, gridview

Я сейчас в школе учусь пользоваться `GridView`. У меня есть таблица `GridView` со всей информацией пользователей.
Когда я хочу делать `UpdateRow`, мы должны имя, фамилию, номер телефона и другие данные сохранить в каждую отдельной переменной.
Наш учитель нам показал, что это надо делать так:

```
GridViewRow changedRow = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
string firstName = ((TextBox)changedRow.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Я не могу понять, что означают  `(TextBox)` и `Controls[0]`? Что именно эти функции делаюn? Для чего они нужны?

Comment: Поменяйте как вам надо и запустите код, что смотрите, сработает ли он.

Comment: Я попробовал стереть (TextBox) и Controls[0] так код не работает. Но я не понял что имено означают эти функции. Мне  хотелось бы узнать их значение и применение.

Comment: Это прямо сильно базовые вещи. Мне кажется, такое будет лучше у учителя спросить.